# Error en compilación al usar la función length sobre Factores de un numero HASKELL

Tags: haskell

Dispongo del siguiente código:

**Funcion Factores**

```
factores ::  Integer -> [Integer]

factores n = [ divisor |divisor <-[1..n], n `mod`divisor == 0 ]
```

**Funcion esPrimo**

```
esPrimo :: Integer -> Bool

esPrimo n = if n == 1 
        then
          False
        else
          length(factores n) == 2
```

Obtengo el siguiente error al compilar la funcion **esPrimo**:

esPrimo.hs:7:26: error:
    Variable not in scope: factores :: Integer -> t0 a0
  |
7 |                   length(factores n) == 2   |                          ^^^^^^^^

¿Sabéis a que puede deberse? Gracias de antebrazo

Comment: No parece que esté importando la función `factores` en `esPrimo.hs`.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, un problema de dependencias